# Wordpress redirecting https to http with a 301 redirect from unknown source

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop

I am trying to redirect all http traffic to https in wordpress. But I don't know why the website is making exactly the inverse process just in front-end. I haven't modified .htaccess file and if I try to install a plugin or to insert any new line to redirect the traffic the website goes in a infinite loop. As you can see here: https://gyazo.com/24c54632e151194a2ad58ce2fb8dbf4b https://gyazo.com/2e64095e3e3895e53aa3f82b77f12003

Do someone know how to find the source of this redirect ?

If you are curious that's the website address: https://gazzettadegliesports.it

UPDATE: .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My next instinct was to check if your SSL certificate was active and indeed it is: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=gazzettadegliesports.it

Next check was Sucuri, and as suspected, you have some malware:
https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/gazzettadegliesports.it

Best to clean up that first. Then, I suggest Really Simple SSL plugin for WordPress.

Comment: Post updated. Also I can't try any method because, if I try, the redirect it works correctly, but seen that there is an inverse redirect it generate a infinite loop

Comment: @RobertoScardigno I updated my post, too. The culprit might be malware. FYI (see Sucuri link above)

Comment: Uuh. Thanks I will let you know if that's the problem